# In winforms which is the best way [many windows form-Mdiparent] or [many usercontrols-one forms]?

Tags: .net, winforms

We are creating a new winforms application. For different purpose we have different user interfaces. But we are not sure whether we should implement this different UI items as

- new windows forms object  -with mdiparent child -
- as usercontrols -one main form and many tabitems containing other pages as usercontrol-

  Which one is the best for developer frindly- user friendly etc? 
   Or are there are any good 3rd party solutions for managing multiple forms in one application in a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're trying to accomplish.

Microsoft used to recommend using MDI when a single program was dealing with multiple documents of the same type (Word, Excel being the canonical examples). But this seems to have fallen out of favor more recently. I note that even the latest versions of office don't use MDI.

If you want to manage multiple documents of the same type in a tab-style interface ala a modern web browser, then Infragistics makes a nice and flexible tab control set (http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wintab.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend MDI forms for the following reasons:

1. You can create parent Form class that will act as your Master with all other MDI forms extending this master Form.
2. With MDI forms, the window management behavior is already handled by the framework. No need to manually implement, minimizing, restore, maximize or closing of window.
3. MDI forms let you display more than one window/control at the same time. Tabs are displayed one-at-a-time. So if your users will compare data between windows, use MDI.
4. You can choose to close MDI forms which will dispose and causes the associated instances of the object to be garbage collected. This will make your app memory efficient. Tabs cannot be closed and your user control instance will always be there in the background (i haven't tested it though).
5. MDI forms have been tested for decades.
6. You will have a cleaner code with MDI forms since you have separate .cs files for each window. With tabs, your code in the form that holds the tabs could grow really big.

Comment: when using mdi forms we want also show users list of the opened pages , and reach all the opened sub mdi's in this menu list ; as you gues this list is nothing different than a tabcontrol . but you are not able to insert a mdi form into a tabcontrol , so you should implement your own tabcontrol just like tabcontrol, or convert this mdi forms to usercontrols ...